# How to disable specific button in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I disable a specific button, but not all, data comes from the server, there can be many buttons, but need to disable a specific one and how can now, by clicking on a button, also disable a specific button and make it so that it is always disabled if the button was pressed?

```
                <div
                               className="card"
                               style={{ width: 18 + "rem" }}
                               key={`${index}`}
                           >
                               <img src={post.url} className="card-img-top" alt="..." />
                               <div className="card-body">
                                   <h5 className="card-title">{post.title}</h5>
                                   <p className="card-text">{post.content}</p>
                                   <a href="/" className="btn btn-primary">
                                       {post.category}
                                   </a>
                                   <button onClick={() => like(index)} disabled >Like</button>
                                   <h3>{post.likes} likes</h3>
                               </div>
                           </div>
```

Comment: you can use the code like <button disabled={disabled}>Like</button>. where disabled is a variable or state in your component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume like(index) updates the index value to something true and false. If so, you can disable based on the index:

```
disabled={index}
```

Comment: thanks for helping me and can you help how can i keep that the button is disabled because when i reload the page the buttons that were clicked are not disabled?

Comment: You need to persist the data than having state, store in localstorage.

Comment: can you please give an example,

P.S I'm just a beginner

Comment: Currently, you're storing them in state. You need to store them in localstorage. For eg. `localStorage.setItem('index', true)`, To get `localStorage.getItem('index')`. This is just an example where storing single index. You have to store all indexes as necessary may be as an object by stringifying.